# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser how to get Third table using find method

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I have HTML code like following structure.

How can I fetch the 3rd table's content from this HTML code using PHP Simple HTML DOM find method?

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td>
              <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              .......
              </table>

          </td>
         <tr>
        ..........
     <td>
  <tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get third table pass second argument(index start from 0) in find method.

```
  $html = file_get_html(<your_file_url/html_code>);    
  $html->find("table", 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The tables are nested so:

```
$dom->find("table", 0); # first table
$dom->find("table table", 0); # second table
$dom->find("table table table", 0); # third table
```

Answer (score 1):

just an idea, try this:

```
// Find first <table> in first <td>
$html = file_get_html('yours.htm');
$var = $html->find('td', 0)->find('table', 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. but its not possible with ->find($pattern) only because I am using it with different-different data.

Comment: what is 'different-different data' means? I just wanna know.

Comment: @egigundari: what is file_get_html(), i did not get any reff for it.

Comment: @egigundari I have created script for getting data/detail from different types of HTML file for that I am using $html->find($pattern) method

Comment: @Suresh Raidon using 'PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser' I guess, you can google it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that sure but you can try something like below:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXML($YourHTML);

//I have written as item(1) to point at the second table
$params = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(1);
```

Comment: Thanks. but its not possible with (PHP simple html dom parser) ->find($pattern) only because I am using it with different-different data.